# AngularJS and BootstrapUI - pass function and argument to BootstrapUI directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-bootstrap

I'd like to pass a function with to BootstrapUI's popover directive. The attribute is normally a string, but I need to do an AJAX call to supply the attribute to the directive. Currently, the popover displays the function as a string e.g. **"showItem(one)"** rather than the result of calling the function, e.g. **"Item is one"**. Thanks!

The HTML

```
    <li ng-repeat="item in items"
      popover-placement="top"
      popover-trigger="mouseenter"
      uib-popover="showItem({{item.id}})">
      {{item.id}}
    </li>
```

The JS

```
app.controller("uibController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
$scope.items = [
    {id: "one"},
    {id: "two"},
    {id: "three"}
];
$scope.showItem = function(item){
    $http.get('url').success(function(response){
    //data for popover directive
    return "Item is " + item.id;
})

};
}]);
```

Codepen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZQOdY

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in items"
          popover-placement="bottom"
          popover-trigger="mouseenter"
          uib-popover="{{showItem(item)}}">
          {{item.id}}
       </div>
```

Comment: I kinda failed here, this works OK but I was meant to mock an ajax call in showItem, I will try to edit the codepen to simulate ajax response. Thanks

Comment: It looks like I will need to write a new directive that then triggers popover, e.g. link(scope,elem){ doAjaxCall.. elem.popover(ajaxResponse) } if that makes sense. I'll return to answer this when I get it working.